# Error running "npm install && npm run dev" when setting up Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, powershell

I'm trying to set up Laravel 8, and I'm getting this error. What do I need to do to fix it?

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\edularavel\Eduzone> php artisan ui vue --auth
Vue scaffolding installed successfully.
Please run "npm install && npm run dev" to compile your fresh scaffolding.
Authentication scaffolding generated successfully.
PS C:\wamp64\www\edularavel\Eduzone> npm install && npm run dev
At line:1 char:13
+ npm install && npm run dev
+             ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
 
PS C:\wamp64\www\edularavel\Eduzone>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're running the commands in PowerShell, but the instructions assume you're running in a standard Unix shell.

In a Unix shell, `a && b` means "run `a`, and if it's successful, run `b`".

So you can follow the instructions just by running the two separate commands yourself:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

You might want to find some tutorials on basic command-line syntax, both to handle situations like this, and so that you don't accidentally run a command you didn't understand, and find you can't undo it.